# .hide() hides on container div click instead of just handle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
    $("#test").draggable({
        handle: "#testheader",
        containment: 'window'
    });
});

$('p#exit').click(function () {
    $('#test').hide();
});
});

<div id="test"><div id="testheader"><p id="exit">Exit</p></div></div>
```

instead of exiting when i click on the p element, it exits when I click the container div as well.

Comment: wouldn't the p go after the '#exit'?

Comment: remove this }); in the last line , or is it a typo? and instead of p#exit just give exit.

Comment: Please create [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2):

Tri this...

```
$(function () {
    $("#test").draggable({
        handle: "#testheader",
        containment: 'window'
    });

    $('#exit').click(function () {
        $('#test').hide();
    });
});
```

erase the `});` over `$('#exit')`

And see this [jSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3SZNh/)